# How parse through an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic-arrays

I have an question with regards to the php array..

I have an array that has an **x** amount values at the end of the array..

For example, the array would would be

```
[1] => 'Hello'
[2] => Value1, Value2, Value3
[3] => Value1, Value2, Value3
[4] => Value1, Value2, Value3
[5] => 'Good Bye'
```

or

```
[1] => 'Hello'
[2] => Value1, Value2, Value3
[3] => Value1, Value2, Value3
[4] => Value1, Value2, Value3
[5] => Value1, Value2, Value3
[6] => Value1, Value2, Value3
[7] => Value1, Value2, Value3
[8] => 'Good Bye'
```

or it could be

```
[1] => 'Hello'
[2] => Value1, Value2, Value3
[3] => 'Good Bye'
```

Here is what I want to do, I want to display the array value from item 2 before the array item containing good bye.

How would I go about doing that?

Thank you,

Comment: What code have you tried so far, and where is the error or issue occurring?

Comment: Yep, please show pieces of code, where we can easily fit in a few statements to do this.
Maybe we even detect that you retrieve the data from a database query, and decide that it can better be implemented in the query

Comment: Is the `[2] => Value1, Value2, Value3` an array? Or string seperated by commas?

Comment: Wait, so basically you just want to go through the array an print in order?

Comment: [2] => Value1, Value2, Value3 is an array key..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the question exactly, is `[2] => Value1, Value2, Value3` an array or a string where the values are separated by commas?

Also, by printing the [2] before the last one, you basically just printing them in order.

```
$array = array (
    1 => 'Hello',
    2 => array('Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3'),
    3 => array('Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3'),
    4 => array('Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3'),
    5 => 'Good Bye'
);

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)===true) {
        foreach ($value as $invalue) {
            if (is_string($invalue)===true) {
                echo $invalue.", ";
            } else {
                echo 'Error? Throw Exception or something';
            }
        }
        echo "<br />";
        // or explode by , if the Value is string
    } elseif (is_string($value)===true) {
        echo $value."<br />";
    } else {
        echo 'Error? Throw Exception or something';
    }
}
```

If you want to print them some other way, store the output before printing it out, you concatenate the current string to the result input and echo it in the end.

```
$result = "";
foreach (..) {
    $result .= $current;
}
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found my solution. I used the array_walk function.